# On trace of product of two matrices

Tags: matrices, trace

For two random square matrices $A$ and $B$, it is known that $tr(AB)=o_{p}(1)$. ($c=o_{P}(1)$ simply means that $c$ is less than any arbitrary small positive number in probability.)

It is also known that the probability limit of matrix $A$ is **strictly** positive definite, and that of matrix $B$ is positive semi-definite.

Given this, how do we know that $B=o_{p}(1)$ for sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof for the deterministic case. I will leave you to extend it to the probabilistic setting.

Let $\lambda_1(M) \le \dotsb \le \lambda_n(M)$ denote the eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix $M$. Thus, for a positiv semi-definite $B$, we have 
$$ tr(AB) = tr(\lambda_1(A)B) + \underbrace{tr((A-\lambda_1(A)I)B)}_{\ge 0} \ge \lambda_1(A) tr(B) = \lambda_1(A) \sum_{I=1}^n \lambda_i(B). $$
As $A$ is positive definite and every pair of norm on $\mathbb R^n$ are equivalent, we have
$$ \|B\|_F \le \frac c{\lambda_1(A)} tr(AB) $$
for a suitable constant $c > 0$ depending only on $n$.
In particular, if $\lambda_1(A)^{-1} = O(1)$ then it follows $\|B\|_F = o(tr(AB)) = o(1)$.

In general it is wrong. Consider $A = \frac{1}{k^2}$ and $B=k$. Then $AB = \frac1k = o(1)$, but $B\ne o(1)$.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Just a quick notice, the example you gave for $A$ is not STRICTLY positive but degenerate.

Comment: @JieWei what is **strictly** positive definite?

Comment: It's positive definite but not positive semi-definite.

Comment: @JieWei what makes you think it doesn't apply to the $A$ in the given counter example?

Comment: Because the LIMIT of A is zero, not strictly positive.

Comment: @JieWei that is just an example, that you can't omit the $\lambda_1(A)^{-1} = O(1)$ assumption.

Comment: Well, $\lambda_{1}(plim_{k\rightarrow \infty} A) = 0$

Comment: @JieWei I don't get your comment. I said you **can't** omit the assumption. I gave an example which violates the assumption.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Thanks.